# simulated annealing applied on TSP

Tags: python, traveling-salesman, simulated-annealing

I have done a brief work on solving TSP using Simulated annealing, and also by brute force. As we know TSP by brute force will take O(n!) steps by checking all possible paths, What I want to ask is that if we allow these many steps using the simulated annealing algorithm, will it get to a correct solution. 
(It is guaranteed that it will yield a sub-optimal solution with lesser no. of iterations, but my quesiton is that can we get the optimal solution if we run it for n! times, where n is the number of cities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; simulated annealing will probably find a close-to-optimal solution very quickly, but there is no guarantee it will ever find the exact optimal solution.

Comment: Thanks. So, is it that the advantage of using SImulated annealing in tsp is just to improve the time required to get a sub-optimal solution. And in case we want an exact solution we must not take this Simulated Annealing approach?

Comment: @PsJain: in many cases a brute force solution is practically impossible (ie would take trillions of years to run) and we have to be content with a good approximation.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea upto what no. of cities can Python give you the solution by brute force? I tried for 100 and it gave the o/p as 'killed'.

Comment: @PsJain: it depends - how efficient is your program? How fast is your computer? How long are you willing to wait? - but in general I would expect anything more than 15 to 20 cities to be untenable. A suggestion - read up on the cprofile module, then time your program solving 10, 11, 12, 13 cities. Graph this, then try to estimate how long it would take to solve 20, 30, 40 cities.